# Что такое static в PHP ООП?

Tags: php, ооп, static

Кто нибудь, розкажите мне что такое static в ООП, и для чего он используется, если можно то и с примером.

Comment: метод/свойство класса. А не объекта класса. [php.net static](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 5):

**Во-первых** это ключевое слово используется для обозначения статических свойств и методов класса, которые принадлежат не к конкретным объектам, а в контексте самого класса. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods)

Я обычно на уроках привожу такой пример – Класс, это чертеж нашего дома, конкретные дома построенные это объекты. Статические свойства это например цвет чернил, которыми чертеж был сделан, или тип бумаги, на котором начертили схему. А цвет конкретных домов и например этажность дома это уже конкретные свойства объектов.

**Во-вторых** зарезервированное слово `static` используется для позднего статического связывания. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

В принципе из названия все понятно. Можно провести аналогию с объектами и сразу станет понятно. `$this` обращается к текущему объекту, а `parent` обращается к свойствам или методам родительского класса. Так вот ту же задачу выполняет слово `static` – `self` для обращения к текущему классу, то есть тому, в котором написан код. А `static` используем, что бы при наследовании получить доступ к классу, который наследовал статические методы или свойства.

И **в третьих** (не относится к ООП). Слово `static` используется для обозначения статичных переменных. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static)

Они нужны, что бы сохранить значения локальных переменных между вызовами. В целом, это как приватные свойства в ООП.

Примеры все есть в документации, как кстати и все описание и даже на русском языке! Не ленитесь, всегда смотрите первоисточник, не доверяйте на 100% книгам и форумам.

Comment: Довольно расширенный ответ с учетом того что человек спрашивал про `static` В ООП, плюсую за это. :)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов дело в том, что намного важнее понимание позднего статического связывания, а статические свойства и методы это намного проще для понимая. Хотя моим студентам бывает сложно это сразу осознать

Answer (score 2):

Он делает поля(свойства) или методы членами класса, именно класса, не объекта а класса, и нам можно будет обращаться к таким методам и свойствам с помощью конструкции двойного двоеточия `ClassName::methodOrElement`, то есть не реализуя и не создавая новый объект, при этом доступ из объектов, к таким свойствам, будет не доступен. Ну основе таких методов реализуют например паттерн `Singleton`(Одиночка).

```
class Singleton 
{
    private static $instance;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_nstance;
    }

    private function __construct() 
    {
            //code
    }
}
```

Тут для реализации одиночки, используется и свойства и методы `Static`.

Подробнее http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php.

Comment: с чего вдруг из объекта нельзя обратиться будет? В статическом методе у вас нет доступа к `$this`, но никто не мешает вызывать статически метод динамически у объекта.

Comment: @teran да, я части не прав, к свойствам нельзя будет, к методам вероятно можно.